# The argument type 'Function' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function()?'. Here i'm not able to pass function

Tags: flutter, function, dart, arguments

[image]

I'm not able to pass function to the Gesture Detector on Tap? But I've seen it worked in previous vesion of dart. Can anyone have a answer to this?

Comment: Please post code as text, not as a screen capture.

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because you defined a function without a return value. That means your function could also return an int, boolean, etc., but the onTap wants to return a void. You need to create a typedef and define the function for this to work.

Create a typedef

```
typedef OnPressCallback = void Function();
```

Declare your function as OnPressCallback type

```
OnPressCallback onPress;
```

Pass it to the onTap

```
onTap: onPress,
```

Or if you dont want to use a typedef you can call it like this:

```
onTap: (){
      onPress.call();
});
```

Btw there are predefined typedefs from the Flutter Framework, so you don't have to define them again:

- **GestureTapCallback**
- **VoidCallback**

Answer (score 0):

There are two easy options:

One:

```
final Function() onPress
```

Two:

`onTap: () => onPress`